# Adding values of two columns on the same row to get a new value

Tags: r, dataframe

Sorry for asking a very basic question but I am new to R and really stuck on a rather simple matter; I have the data frame below (2 rows and 7 columns):

```
Sub    sup_b       hdt   sup_2      lbnp    sup_3    hut    sup_4
6       175        434     596       585    601      593    211
7       130        592     592       593    600      384    166
```

These values correspond with time duration (secs) for seven test conditions

```
col$names <- c(sup_b, hdt, sup_2, lbnp, sup_3, hut, sup_4)
```

and 17 rows (each row is for one study subject- I have only included first two rows).

I am trying to add values from row 1 `col$sup_b` (175) and row 1 `col$hdt` (434) to get the combined duration for the first two conditions i.e. 609 secs. I then add the value of the previous two cols (609) to the next `col$sup_2` to get the total duration (609 + 596) and so on until the last condition `col$sup_4`.

I have tried the method below which is for subject 6 (row 1), which works fine, but I want to tidy this up and make it easier as I have 17 subjects (rows) and have been advised there is an easier way around this:

```
sup_b <- 175
hdt <- (sup_b + 434)
sup_2 <- (hdt + 596)
lbnp <- (sup_2 + 585)
sup_3 <- (hdt_lbnp + 601)
hut <- (sup_3 + 593)
sup_4 <- (hut + 211)
```

I want to be able to just change the number of row and have the data pulled across from the data frame rather than entering each individual time period; for instance:

```
line <- 1 ### the row I want which corresponds to the subject 
sup_b <- df[line, 2]
hdt <-df[line, 2] + df[line, 3]
```

but I keep getting this warning message:

> In Ops.factor(df[line, 2], df[line, 3]) : ‘+’ not meaningful for factor

I have even tried: `colSums(df[,c(2:3)])`, but get the following warning:

> Error in colSums(df[, c(2:3)]) : 'x' must be numeric.

also tried: `st$sum <- apply(df[,c(2:3)], 1, sum)`, which doesn't work either.

Comment: `apply(df,1,cumsum)`? to get everything or as suggested, `rowSums` to obtain the sum

Comment: could you provide `summary` of you data? looks like they are factors. Convert to numeric by using `sapply(df, function(x) s.numeric(as.character(x)))`

Comment: How are you creating your `data.frame` ? I suspect your numeric values are read as a string and strings are automatically converted to factors. This could happen if you are reading with `header = FALSE` and there actually is a header that is a string.

Answer (score 1):

```
df1[-1] <- t(apply(df1[-1],1,cumsum))
#   Sub sup_b hdt sup_2 lbnp sup_3  hut sup_4
# 1   6   175 609  1205 1790  2391 2984  3195
# 2   7   130 722  1314 1907  2507 2891  3057
```

**data**

```
df1 <- read.table(text="Sub    sup_b       hdt   sup_2      lbnp    sup_3    hut    sup_4
6       175        434     596       585    601      593    211
7       130        592     592       593    600      384    166",h=T,strin=F)
```